# Automapper ForPath mapping and unmapped property exception

Tags: c#, automapper

Im trying to map (while validating by `MemberList.Source`) nested member from the source property like

```
 .ForPath(target => target.NestedObj.IpAddress, opt=>opt.MapFrom(source => source.IpAddress))
```

but when validationg configuration it throws

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: 
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
```

I know I could ignore the propety but I'd like to avoid it if possible.